# PHP file_put_contents retorna FALSE

Tags: php, android

**Descripción:**

Desde mi aplicación movil android estoy tomando una foto con la cámara cuyo Bitmap lo encodeo en Base64 para enviarselo a mi servicio .php el cual lo decodea para guardar la imagen en el servidor.

**Como encodeo desde android:**

```
private fun encodeImage(bm: Bitmap): String? {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
    val b = baos.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

Envío el base64 con el nombre de "productImage"

**Como decodeo desde PHP para enviar al server**

```
$businessId= $_POST["businessId"];
$productImage = $_POST["productImage"];
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $productImage));

/* Nombre del archivo en carpeta */
$path = "productsimgs/"."b$businessId.jpg";
/* Ruta de la imagen  (bd) */
$url = "productsimgs/"."b".$businessId.".jpg";
echo json_encode(file_put_contents($path,$data));
```

**Ubicación de mi carpeta productsimgs:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El problema:**

Cuando ejecuto el servicio php, el echo del file_put_contents retorna "false". Al revisar mi carpeta productsimgs no se guarda la imagen. Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: ya validaste que contiene la variable $productImage; te recomiendo comenzar validando que realmente hayas recibido el string de la imagen y que este completo dicho string ... por otro lado me parece muy mala practica... seria 100% preferible envies el archivo no un string base64

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 gracias por responder. Si validé, y $productImage está viniendo con la string base64. Como valido que esté completo? a que te referis con eso?. y a que te referis con enviar el archivo?

Comment: para validar que este completo tienes que mostrar el string en tu app y luego comparar la extension del mismo string de lado del servidor ... estoy casi seguro que puedes tener problemas con el tamaño del string... ya que en memoria estaria ocupado mas espacio que una imagen nativa... y por eso te digo que es preferible enviar los archivos tal cual en lugar de convertirlos en base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que estás recibiendo correctamente los datos y `$productImage` tiene el código en Base64, hay dos errores que estás cometiendo.

**Rutas relativas**

En la función [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents) estás usando una [ruta relativa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_relativa). Y con esto le indicás que la ubicación se encuentra en la misma carpeta en la cual está el script.

Si el script está en: `carpeta_proyecto/src/mi_script.php`, entonces le estás indicando que guarde en `carpeta_proyecto/src/productsimgs/etc...`. Y supongo que no querés tener en la misma carpeta de tu código las imágenes que serán de acceso público. **Supongo**.

Lo suyo es que uses [rutas absolutas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_absoluta) para no tener ese problema.

**Base64 Decode**

La función [base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-decode) decodifica la cadena y lo que te devuelve está en formato binario. Tu problema está en que lo usás dos veces.

```php
// Aquí
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $productImage));

//...

// y aquí
echo json_encode(file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($data)));
```

Deberías eliminar el uso de la función en el `file_put_contents`.

```php
echo json_encode(file_put_contents($path, $data));
```

**Otra cosa**

La función **file_put_contents** [devuelve](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-returnvalues) el número de bytes que fueron escritos en el fichero o `false` en caso contrario. Si después de solucionar lo de arriba sigue indicando `false` fijate que tengas los permisos para escribir en la carpeta donde lo vas a guardar.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta. Resolviste mi problema. Primero me hiciste notar mi doble uso de base64_decode, y por ultimo y lo más importante me hiciste notar que la ruta que especifiqué, hacía referencia a una carpeta dentro de la carpeta en donde está mi script, en lugar de apuntar a una carpeta por fuera de esa. Gracias infinitas!!!!